# How to convert html to json in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-html

My api getting 200 status code and also get html response. so how to convert html data into json data in dart?

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70350073/dart-convert-html-to-json#answer-70350277

Comment: Not working solution @RobinHood. can u share more?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

If you're trying to send data from the page you can extract data from the DOM like so...

```
<input id="superId">information</input>
<input id="otherId">information</input>  

<script>
   let myJson = {
      'super': document.getElementById('#superId').value,
      'other': document.getElementById('#otherId').value
   }

   // Call server with myJson as data attribute to post data

</script>
```

If you are trying to receive data you may need to process the response with `json.parse(response)` before you can access the object like `response.data` hope this helps